# Cpp: Why the next regex match is not correct?

Tags: c++

I have th next code sample:

```
    std::string str("example1   ");
    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex e("[a-zA-Z_]+[0-9a-zA-Z_]*\s*");
    if (std::regex_match(str, sm, e))
    {
        std::cout << "ok_match";
    }
```

It should accept everything including spaces, but it doesn't.
For example, if the string will be:

```
std::string str("example1");
```

So "ok_match" will be print on the screen.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not escaped the `"\s"` sequence correctly.  Actually, your compiler should be showing you a warning like

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:16: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\s'
   std::regex e("[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*\s*");
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

To represent a regex pattern such as `\s` in a C++ string, you will need to escape the backslash in order to get a literal backslash in your string.  To elaborate a bit:

- `"\n"` represents a linebreak.  You've probably seen that before.
- `"\\n"` represents a backslash, followed by the letter `n`.
- In the same vein, `"\s"` is treated as an escape sequence by the compiler, except the sequence `"\s"` does not actually exist.
- You want an *actual* backslash +`s` in your string, so you need to write `"\\s"`: a backslash, followed by the letter `s`.  This, in turn, is understood by `std::regex` to be a shorthand for whitespace.

This program should do what you are looking for:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string str("example1   ");
  std::smatch sm;
  std::regex e("[a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*\\s*");
  if (std::regex_match(str, sm, e))
  {
    std::cout << "ok_match";
  }
}
```

<kbd>Live on coliru</kbd>